# C++ get iteratorposition of delimiter

Tags: c++, string, iterator, delimiter

Could someone help me, i have problem with the string iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string s("foo $deli: baa :deli$ no matter")
string deli_open ("$deli:");
string deli_close (":deli$");

string::const_iterator it_begin = s.begin();
string::const_iterator it_end = s.begin();

// calculate won't work because I need the Iterposition! 
size_t found = s.find(deli_open);

if (found != string::npos)
   cout << found << '\n';

// your idea

// return $deli: baa :deli$
for( string::const_iterator i = it_begin; i != it_end; ++i)
{
  cout << (*i) ;
}

cout << endl;
```

this should be the solution:

Return iteratorposion it_begin at "$deli: baa :deli$ no matter"

Return iteratorposition it_end at "foo $deli: baa :deli$"

Comment: `string::const_iterator it_end = s.begin();` ??

Comment: C++ have many nice [functions for handling iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator), for example one which can be used to get the [distance between two iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). Use it in the loop to compare with the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking - I assume you are looking for an iterator that points one past the end of the closing delimiter.
This can be done with the following steps:

1. after you found the opening delimiter, search *from there* for the closing delimiter.
2. after you have found that (the iterator you got from that search will point to the start of it), advance the iterator by N positions, N being the length of the closing delimiter:

   ```
   using namespace std;
   int main() {
     string s("foo $deli: baa :deli$ no matter")
     string deli_open ("$deli:");
     string deli_close (":deli$");

     size_t startOpenDelim = s.find(deli_open);
     if (startOpenDelim == string::npos)
       cerr << "opening delimiter not found\n";

     size_t startCloseDelim = s.find(deli_close, startOpenDelim);
     if (startCloseDelim == string::npos)
       cerr << "closing delimiter not found\n";

     size_t endCloseDelim = startCloseDelim + deli_close.length();

     string::const_iterator it_begin = s.begin() + startOpenDelim;
     string::const_iterator it_end = s.begin() + endCloseDelim;

     cout << string(it_begin, it_end) << endl;
   }
   ```